# How can I improve the accuracy of my pytorch neural network for classification of tabular data?

Tags: neural-network, classification, pytorch

As a newbie in 'pytorch', I am building a neural network for classification of faulty water pumps in Tazania for [this competition](https://www.drivendata.org/competitions/7/pump-it-up-data-mining-the-water-table/) I am also using `ax-platform` for hyperparameter tuning.

Yes methods such as gradient boosting classifiers and random forest probably works well or even better than neural network classifier for this tabular data problem but I want to practice using `pytorch`.

The problem is that when I am doing `optimise` from `ax-platform` I am  **getting accuracy score not more than 54%** and I wish to improve that. It jumps around certain number only as shown here:

[image: accuracy]

I tried to do some debugging in my evaluate function by printing out predicted and labels

```
def evaluate(net, testloader):
        correct = 0
        total = 0
        with torch.no_grad():
            for data in testloader:
                inputs, labels = map(Variable,data)
                outputs = net(inputs)
                _,predicted = torch.max(outputs,1)
      
                print("row in testloader")
                print("predicted: ")
                print(predicted)
                print("labels: ")
                print(labels)
                total += labels.size(0)
                correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
                # print(str(correct)+"/"+str(total))
        print('Accuracy of the network: %d %%' % (
            100 * correct / total))
        return 100 * correct / total
```

and `net(inputs)` is giving a tensor of all ones. It should have been a tensors with varied classifications/numbers of [0,1,2] .

[image]

I have tried (maybe not well):

- using SGD and ADAM
- 1,2 and 3 hidden layers
- different epoches
- 'Dropout' with different dropout probabilites
- disabling biases
- having different learning rates
- different number of neurons
- different total trails
- different betas and eps for ADAM algorithm
- 'log_scale = True' in parameters optimsation
- `sci-kit learn` `StandardScaler` on `train_values` and `test_values`
  But none broke the barrier.

How can I break the 54% accuracy barrier here? What are the gaps in my knowledges? What bugs in the code that causes this?

Here is the code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import torch
import torchvision
import torchvision.transforms as transforms
from ax import optimize
from ax.plot.contour import plot_contour
from ax.plot.trace import optimization_trace_single_method
from ax.utils.notebook.plotting import render
from sklearn import preprocessing
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder, OrdinalEncoder, StandardScaler
from torch import functional, nn, optim
from torch.autograd import Variable
import math
rng =0

ordinalEncorder  = OrdinalEncoder()
labelEncoder = LabelEncoder()
standardScaler = StandardScaler()

d = {
    "funder": "string","installer": "string",
    "wpt_name": "string",    "basin": "string",
    "subvillage": "string",    "region": "string",    "lga": "string",    "ward": "string",
    "public_meeting": "string",    "recorded_by": "string",    "scheme_management": "string",
    "scheme_name": "string",    "permit": "string",
    "extraction_type": "string",    "extraction_type_group": "string",    "extraction_type_class": "string",
    "management": "string",
    "management_group": "string",    "payment": "string",
    "payment_type": "string",
    "water_quality": "string",    "quality_group": "string",
    "quantity": "string",    "quantity_group": "string",    "source": "string",
    "source_type": "string",
    "source_class": "string",    "waterpoint_type": "string",
    "waterpoint_type_group": "string",
    "date_recorded": "string",
}

str_cat= [
    "funder","installer",
    "wpt_name" ,    "basin",
    "subvillage",    "region",
    "lga",    "ward",
    "public_meeting",    "recorded_by",
    "scheme_management",    "scheme_name",
    "permit",    "extraction_type",
    "extraction_type_group",
    "extraction_type_class",    "management",
    "management_group",
    "payment",    "payment_type",    "water_quality",    "quality_group",
    "quantity",
    "quantity_group",    "source",
    "source_type",    "source_class",
    "waterpoint_type",
    "waterpoint_type_group",
    "date_recorded",
]

test_values =pd.read_csv("./test-set-values.csv")
train_values = pd.read_csv("./training-set-values.csv")
train_labels = pd.read_csv("./training-set-labels.csv")
length = train_values.shape[0]
train_batch_size = 100 
test_batch_size= 100

train_labels['status_group'] = labelEncoder.fit_transform(train_labels.status_group.astype('string'))
train_values[str_cat] = ordinalEncorder.fit_transform(train_values[str_cat].astype(d).fillna(""))
test_values[str_cat] = ordinalEncorder.fit_transform(test_values[str_cat].astype(d).fillna(""))

train_values[str_cat] = standardScaler.fit_transform(train_values[str_cat])
test_values[str_cat]=standardScaler.fit_transform(test_values[str_cat])

train_values = train_values.astype('float32').values
test_values = test_values.astype('float32').values
train_labels = train_labels.status_group.astype('long').values

x_train,x_test,y_train,y_test = map(torch.from_numpy, 
                                    train_test_split(train_values,train_labels,test_size=0.2,
                                                 random_state=rng,shuffle=True))

train = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_train,y_train)
test = torch.utils.data.TensorDataset(x_test,y_test)
train_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(train,batch_size=train_batch_size,shuffle = False)
test_loader = torch.utils.data.DataLoader(test,batch_size=test_batch_size,shuffle = False)

class Net(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self,hidden1,hidden2,dropoutProbabilities1):
        super(Net,self).__init__()
        
        self.layer1 = nn.Linear(40,hidden1,)
        self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden1,hidden2)
        self.layer3 = nn.Linear(hidden2,3)
        # self.layer2 = nn.Linear(hidden1,3) # layer 2 configuration if layer 3 is not used.
        self.layer4 = nn.Linear(3,3,)
        self.activation =nn.ReLU()
        self.dropout1 = nn.Dropout(p=dropoutProbabilities1)
        # self.dropout2 = nn.Dropout(p=dropoutProbabilities2)
        # self.batchNormalisation1 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden1)
        # self.batchNormalisation2 = nn.BatchNorm1d(hidden2)
    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.layer1(x)
        # x = self.batchNormalisation1(x)
        
        x = self.layer2(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
#         x = self.batchNormalisation2(x)

        x = self.layer3(x)
        x = self.activation(x)
        x = self.dropout1(x)
        x = self.layer4(x)
        return x

def train(net, parameterization, trainloader):
    optimizer = optim.Adam(net.parameters(),
                           lr=parameterization['lr'],
                           weight_decay=parameterization['weight_decay'], 
                
                           maximize = True
                           )
    criterion = nn.CrossEntropyLoss()

    for epoch in range(5):  
        for data in trainloader:
            inputs, labels = map(Variable,data)
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            loss = criterion(net(inputs), labels)
            loss.backward()
            optimizer.step()
    return net

def evaluate(net, testloader):
    correct = 0
    total = 0
    with torch.no_grad():
        for data in testloader:
            inputs, labels = map(Variable,data)
            outputs = net(inputs)
            _,predicted = torch.max(outputs,1)
  
            # print("row in testloader")
            # print("predicted: ")
            # print(predicted)
            # print("labels: ")
            # print(labels)
            total += labels.size(0)
            correct += (predicted == labels).sum().item()
            # print(str(correct)+"/"+str(total))
    print('Accuracy of the network: %d %%' % (
        100 * correct / total))
    return 100 * correct / total

def train_evaluate(parameters):
    net = Net(parameters["hidden1"],parameters['hidden2'],parameters['dropoutProbabilities1'])
    # net = Net(parameters["hidden1"],parameters['hidden2'])
    net = train(net, parameters, train_loader)
    return evaluate(net, test_loader)
parameters=[
        {"name": "lr", "type": "range",
         "value_type":'float', "bounds": [0.001, 0.5],'log_scale':True},
        {"name": "weight_decay", "type": "range",
         "value_type":'float',"bounds": [0.1, 0.9999],'log_scale':True},
        {"name": "hidden1", "type":"range",
           "value_type":'int',"bounds":[5,1100],'log_scale':True},
         {"name": "hidden2", "type":"range",
            "value_type":'int',"bounds":[5,1100],'log_scale':True},
    {"name":"dropoutProbabilities1","type":"range","value_type"
     :"float","bounds":[0.1,0.4]},

    ]
best_parameters, values, experiment, model = optimize(
    parameters= parameters,
    evaluation_function=train_evaluate,
    objective_name='accuracy',
    minimize=False,
    total_trials=10
)
```

Comment: It seems that you are currently only training your model for 5 epochs, how many epochs have tried? In addition, you currently are not using any activation function for your first layer, adding this might improve results a bit. The first step would probably to try and start overfitting your model on the training data (even on just a single batch as described in [this blogpost on training neural networks from Andrej Karpathy](http://karpathy.github.io/2019/04/25/recipe/)) before making sure the model performs well on the test data.

Comment: I did try like 10 epochs the other time. and okay, I will try out these suggestions

Comment: Welp I have tried your suggestions including diving deeper in the post you have linked but Im not having much improvments or im just confused.